# For Loop Counter Always Resets in C# Recursive Function

Tags: c#, .net

I have a strange problem that I don't get it fully. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

I have a for loop in a recursive function that gets reset always even when the loop counter is an instance variable of the class. Why? Here is the code:

```
public class Products{
    private int loopCounter=1;
    private int loop=10;
    public int ProductCount {get;set;}
    public int GetProducts(int Take, int Skip)
    {
        //code that sets ProductCount is removed
        for (int loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < loop; loopCounter++)
        {
            //Depending on ProductCount, Take and Skip values are
            //computed and passed to GetProducts. This code removed for brevity and am hard coding them
            GetProducts(10,5);
            //code to process GetProducts output removed
        }
    } 
}
```

For reasons that I don't get, the loopCounter always gets reset to 1 and the loop goes on forever. Shouldn't the loop stop after 10 iterations?

Comment: The code you have posted is an infinite loop. If you have some other logic branch where `GetProducts()` is not being called within itself, please post it. The code is running as designed.

Comment: Basically you have a scoping problem where a variable name shares the same name as a field.  If you name your C# field members to follow best practices you can avoid this sort of thing.  Consider renaming `private int loopCounter` to `private int _loopCounter`.

Comment: @MickyD Renaming the variable as suggested doesn't solve the problem and as you mentioned, it seems like a scope problem.

Comment: No...but it does eliminate any confusion and makes it apparent _where the problem resides_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating and setting a new method level variable `loopCounter` in the beginning of your for loop every time you call the function. If you want to use the class level variable, you should remove the first part of the for loop (something like `for(; loopCounter < loop; loopCounter++)`

That said, I wouldn't recommend using a loop to control recursion like this. It would be better to use just a loop or have GetProducts return when it has hit the boundary condition.

```
public class Products{
private int loopCounter=1;
private int loop=10;
public int ProductCount {get;set;}
public int GetProducts(int Take, int Skip)
{
    if(loopCounter >= loop) return;
    loopCounter++;
    //code that sets ProductCount is removed
    //Depending on ProductCount, Take and Skip values are
    //computed and passed to GetProducts. This code removed for brevity and am hard coding them
    GetProducts(10,5);
    //code to process GetProducts output removed
}
```

Comment: Removing the loopCounter from the loop as suggested like this: for (; loopCounter < loop; loopCounter++){} does not work. The loopCounter is still reset to 1 always as if the for loop is implicitly creating a "for scoped" local variable and initializing its value to 1 everytime the loop is called. The for loop behaves as if the class level loopCounter variable does not even exist! I removed the for loop entirely and replaced it with a "while" loop which worked just fine. @Hofma Dresu recommendation also works. I am still baffled as to why the for loop did not work.

Comment: Another reason the loop wasn't working is because the "loopCounter++" statement is never actually run. You enter the for loop with loopCounter = 1 then recursively call GetProducts _before_ incrementing loopCounter. This means loopCounter is still 1 (and will always be 1) when GetProducts is called

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little confused by what is actually inside the loop besides GetProducts(), but it seems that you do not have a condition to stop. You run the loop once starting from 1, then you call the function again and a new loop starting from 1 is created. You need to create a condition to stop this infinite call mechanism so it will go back to already existing calls.

Comment: OP is aware that he needs a stop condition with the statement _"the loopCounter always gets reset to 1 and the loop goes on forever. Shouldn't the loop stop after 10 iterations?"_

Comment: @Ncs The GetProducts() does not alter the loop variables at all. It just connects to the database and returns the number of product items available in stock.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the variable `loopCounter` is differents of the global one, and you are creating a new one each time you call the function, try to remove this: `int loopCounter = 1` from the for loop.

Comment: @MickyD, sorry but I don´t get what you mean

Comment: Sorry @MickyD , I got it now, you are right, I did´t speak so well

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to return the number of recursive function calls, or the Count in other words, then this code sample will help.

```
public class Products{
    
    public int GetProducts(int Take)
    {
        // Check if you are ready to return the count.

        if (/* Some condition to check. */)
        {
           // Returned value will be 0, if you don't call method
           // recursive, which is equivalent to counter == 0.

           return 0;
        }
        
        // Do some stuff here and get result.

        // Returned value will be 1 + next value of the Method
        // call, which is whether 0 or 1 if recursion goes further.
        // All together, the end value will be the count of
        // recursive method calls.

        return 1 + GetProducts(result);
    } 
}
```